# notation –replace n lowest/highest numbers in a vector

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors

I have a vector $v$ and would like to get to $v'$, where the $n$ highest elements of $v'$ are equal to $v$, otherwise they are $0$.

So for example:

If $v = [1,3,5,3,4]$, and $n = 2$ then $v' = [0,0,5,0,4]$

What would be an acceptable mathematical notation for such a transformation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What if $v=[1,3,5,3,-4]$ and $n=2$?

Comment: @skyking The way I interpreted the question, it would be $v'=[0,3,5,3,0]$

Comment: Once you decide how to handle things like the case in skyking's comment, you're probably better off writing pseudocode. This is a subtle enough transformation and not naturally suited to notation with a more mathematical flavor.

Answer (score 0):

A 'hacky' way of writing it would be:

If $v=[v_0,\cdots, v_k]$, and $n=1$ then $v'=[v'_0,\cdots, v'_k]$ where

$$v'_i=\begin{cases}v_i&v_i=\max\{v\}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

If $v=[v_0,\cdots, v_k]$, and $n=2$ then $v'=[v'_0,\cdots, v'_k]$ where

$$v'_i=\begin{cases}v_i&v_i=\max\{v\}\\
v_i&v_i=\max\{v\backslash\max\{v\}\}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Where the second line is the maximum function of the original set with the maximum value removed

We continue in this vein for all values of $n$, although I can't currently think of a way to actually write it for a general case